# How to move my website to wordpress?

Tags: migration

I am in need to move a website from okaycms to wordpress, but I can't seem to find efficient way to do that. Can someone please tell me how to do that. I guess there is always option to rebuild everything in wordpress, but that wouldn't be so great of a choice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'easy' way to 'move' or 'convert' a static site to WordPress. That's because WP is database-oriented, with content in the database. The themes/plugins/WP-engine take care of creating/building pages from the database content.

So, if you have a static site (HTML or HTML/PHP), you are going to need to find a theme that makes the site look how you want it to, then manually create pages with your page content.

Comment: Okey, thank you.